# How to connect two client desktops with private IP address?

Tags: networking, vpn

**Path**

```
1. Client A (private IP)  ----- (private IP NAT) Router A
2. Router A (dynamic public IP)  ----- Internet
3. Internet ------ (dynamic public IP) Router B
4. Router B (private IP NAT) ----- (private IP) Client B
5. Client B (LAN B) --- (LAN B GW) Router
6. Router (Subnets)
```

**How could we have client A to "bridge" to LAN B?**

**So that:**

- Client A can use IP that's belongs to LAN B and pretend that it is in
  LAN B
- Client A should also be able to see broadcast traffic from LAN
  B, e.g. ARP
- Client A can get an IP from DHCP server in LAN B
- Client A vpn client can configure a list of routes for subnet behind client B.

**Environment:**

- Client A could be Ubuntu/Windows.
- Client B could be Ubuntu VM in proper server or raspberry-pi.
- Encrypted VPN tunnel will be preferred.

Comment: What have you tried? What worked, what didn't work? Which programs did googling for "VPN" turn up?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for your requirements #1 and #2?